# How do you document.writeln() a hyperlink?

Tags: javascript

Very simply question I can't seem to find solved here.

How can I use javascript to print a hyperlink? I'm very beginner with JavaScript and I need something like the following to work:

```
document.writeln("<a href="javascript:toggleDummy1();">" + flaggedKCSarticles.flag_object[i].feedback_text + "</a>");
```

Comment: I recommend avoiding dynamic html construction in JavaScript if possible. It's much cleaner to use template binding

Comment: Don't forget to [avoid `document.write`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice) (when you have learned how to escape strings)

Answer (score 2):

**1) Escape the internal quotes by adding a backslash:**

```
document.writeln("<a href=\"javascript:toggleDummy1();\">" +    
    flaggedKCSarticles.flag_object[i].feedback_text + "</a>");
```

OR

**2) Use single quotes:**

```
document.writeln('<a href="javascript:toggleDummy1();">' +    
    flaggedKCSarticles.flag_object[i].feedback_text + "</a>");
```

Answer (score 2):

Double quotes " are conflicting. Use a single quote in outermost, and double quotes to wrap href attribute.

So it may look like:

```
document.writeln('<a href="javascript:toggleDummy1();">' + flaggedKCSarticles.flag_object[i].feedback_text + '</a>')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to adjust quotes and double quotes so they doesn't conflict.

However, `document.write` and the like are very poor practice. You will learn soon enough that you need to append in a container rather than "brute print" into a document.

For example:

```
var a = document.createElement("a");
a.href = "javascript:toggleDummy1();";

// a more semantic way could be:
//
//   a.onclick=function(event){
//       toggleDummy1();
//   }
//

a.innerText = flaggedKCSarticles.flag_object[i].feedback_text;
document.body.appendChild(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem in your markup, try this

```
document.writeln("<a href=\"javascript:toggleDummy1();\">" + flaggedKCSarticles.flag_object[i].feedback_text + "</a>");
```

or

```
document.writeln("<a href='javascript:toggleDummy1();'>" + flaggedKCSarticles.flag_object[i].feedback_text + "</a>");
```

Answer (score -1):

change your syntax like that,

```
document.writeln('<a href="javascript:toggleDummy1();">' + flaggedKCSarticles.flag_object[i].feedback_text + '</a>');
```

i hope this will work